# The method orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Employee

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

While creating a Spring Boot Controller for Employee CRUD operation, I tried using the orElseThrow method but gives and error `The method orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Employee`. Can any one please help me to solve this issue.

```
package com.mkknowledge.managerportal.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.Optional;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.mkknowledge.managerportal.model.Employee;
import com.mkknowledge.managerportal.service.EmployeeService;
import com.mkknowledge.managerportal.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping({ "/employees" })
public class EmployeeController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    
    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public List<Employee> listEmployee() {
        return employeeService.listAll();
    }
    

    
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        
        Employee emp = employeeService.get(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee", "id", id));
        
        employeeService.delete(id);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

I have also created the custom ResourceNotFoundException class to handle the exception.

```
public ResourceNotFoundException(String resourceName, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
        super(String.format("%s not found with %s : '%s'", resourceName, fieldName, fieldValue));
        this.resourceName = resourceName;
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }
```

added employee Class for further referance

```
package com.mkknowledge.managerportal.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@Entity
@Table( name = "employee",
uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")})
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long empId;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String firstname;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String lastname;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String address;
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyy-mm-dd")
    private Date dob;
     
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 10)
    private String mobile;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String city;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Employee() {
        
    }
    
    public Long getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }



    public void setEmpId(Long empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }



    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }



    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }



    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }



    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    
    
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((city == null) ? 0 : city.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dob == null) ? 0 : dob.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((empId == null) ? 0 : empId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((firstname == null) ? 0 : firstname.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastname == null) ? 0 : lastname.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((mobile == null) ? 0 : mobile.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
            return false;
        if (city == null) {
            if (other.city != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
            return false;
        if (dob == null) {
            if (other.dob != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dob.equals(other.dob))
            return false;
        if (empId == null) {
            if (other.empId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!empId.equals(other.empId))
            return false;
        if (firstname == null) {
            if (other.firstname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstname.equals(other.firstname))
            return false;
        if (lastname == null) {
            if (other.lastname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastname.equals(other.lastname))
            return false;
        if (mobile == null) {
            if (other.mobile != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!mobile.equals(other.mobile))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    
}
```

employee Service get method

```
    public Employee get(long id) {
        return employeeRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
```

Comment: That means `employeeService.get(id)` returns an `Employee` object, *not* `Optional<Employee>`

Comment: please show your Employee class

Comment: And your EmployeeService class (at least the `get(id)` method).

Comment: @ernest_k  do I need to change the return type of get method to Optional<Employee>

Comment: You need to return the object as it is from service class which you are getting from repository `Optional` if you want. to use `orElseThrow`, which is defined in `Optional` class, not in your employee class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Change:

```
return employeeRepository.findById( id ).get() ;
```

… to:

```
return employeeRepository.findById( id ) ;
```

…while changing the declaration of the return type from `Employee` to `Optional< Employee >`.

## `Optional< Employee >`

Apparently you refer to the [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) method of the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class. The `Optional` class is a wrapper around an object reference. An `Optional` object either contains a payload (a reference to another object) or contains nothing.

The purpose of `Optional` is to make obvious the situation where returning a `null` would be legitimate (versus an error condition). Returning an `Optional` removes that ambiguity of returning a `null` where we cannot know if (a) there is simply no value available to be returned, or if (b) something went wrong with the null sent as a signal of failure. In modern Java the (a) scenario is best represented with an object of `Optional` type, while the (b) scenario is best represent by throwing an exception.

Your code:

```java
Employee emp = 
    employeeService
        .get(id)
        .orElseThrow( () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee", "id", id ) );
```

… can only work if the call to your `employeeService` object’s `get(id)` method returned an object of type `Optional< Employee >`. Given your reports, apparently that is not the case.

I would guess your `get(id)` call returns an `Employee` object rather than an `Optional< Employee >` object.

Indeed, that is the case if your code:

```java
    // `EmployeeService` class
    public Employee get( long id ) {
        return employeeRepository.findById( id ).get() ;
    }
```

… is meant to be a method on your `EmployeeService` method. That code is calling `findById( id )` which apparently returns an `Optional< Employee >`. The problem is that method goes on to call `get`.

Solution: Drop that call to `get` inside your `EmployeeService#get` method. Just return the `Optional< Employee >` object returned by the `findById` call. So your code would look like this:

```java
    // `EmployeeService` class
    public Optional< Employee > get( long id ) {
        return employeeRepository.findById( id ) ;
    }
```

The bigger picture might be explained by the [Comment from chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66848038/the-method-orelsethrow-is-undefined-for-the-type-employee/66848378#comment118165232_66848378).

Comment: Speculation: OP is using Spring Data 1, which returned null for record-not-found, but is using a tutorial using Spring Data 2, which switched to returning `Optional`.