# Spring Boot - The method orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

**[NOTE]**

So I'm just going to get this out of the way before anyone asks; yes, I did read [this post regarding a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66848038/the-method-orelsethrow-is-undefined-for-the-type-employee) and while I believe I understand the answer that was provided, it doesn't seem like it's entirely relevant to my issue. I suspect that my issue is more mundane than the one given in that answer. Maybe I'm right or maybe I'm even more misguided on this issue than I first thought. We'll see.

## Introduction:

I'm working on creating a set of exception handlers for a Spring Boot server for a book website and I've been using a variety of references while doing so; namely [this one from ZetCode](https://zetcode.com/springboot/controlleradvice/) and [another from Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring). You'll see influences from them throughout chunks of the following code so it seem pertinent to provide them.

The issue comes up when I attempt to use the method **".orElseThrow()"** in one of my service requests for finding a specific book by its ID. The program compiles and runs but throws a **status 500** error and promptly tells reports the error `The method orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type List<Book>`.

It should be noted that every request to any mapping that doesn't have **".orElseThrow()"** in it works perfectly including the method in question when the problematic line is commented out.

The code is below.

## Code:

The following chunks of code are heavily truncated to make everything more readable. There are a lot of classes at play and some them have a lot of code. I'll happily provide anything that may seem needed if I overlooked it.

**The problematic bit of code is the "getSpecificBook" method in BookServiceImpl but I've included everything that effects that piece of code as well.**

### BookService - Interface

```
public interface BookService {
    public abstract List<Book> getBooks();
    public abstract List<Book> getSpecificBook(int id);
}
```

### BookServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService{
    @Autowired BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return bookRepository.getAllBooks();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getSpecificBook(int id) {
        return bookRepository.findBybookID(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException(id));
    }
    
}
```

### BookServiceController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/books")
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:8080")
public class BookServiceController {
    
    @Autowired BookService bookServicesImpl;
    
    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getBooks() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookServicesImpl.getBooks(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path="/specific/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getSpecificBook(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookServicesImpl.getSpecificBook(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

### BookRepository

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Integer>{

    @Procedure("GetAllBooks")
    List<Book> getAllBooks();
    
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value=baseQuery+" where bookID=:bookID")
    List<Book> findBybookID(@Param("bookID") int bookID);
    
}
```

### Book Entity

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotEmpty
    int bookID;
    
    @NotEmpty
    String title;
    String series_name;
    @NotEmpty
    String author;
    String first_name;
    String middle_name;
    String last_name;
    String publisher_name;
    String isbn;
    String genre_name;
    String notes;

}
```

All of the getter methods are there but have been omitted from the code here for brevity.

### ControllerAdvisor

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {BookNotFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBookNotFoundExcpetion(BookNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> errorMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        errorMap.put("time",LocalDateTime.now());
        errorMap.put("message","Book not Found");
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMap, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

### BookNotFoundException

```
public class BookNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    
    public BookNotFoundException(int id) {
        super(String.format("Book with ID of %d not found.",id));
    }
}
```

## What I've Tried:

The biggest thing I attempted was converting the return type from `List<Book>` to merely "Book" since the List return type isn't strcitly necessary for returning a single result but even then, it still wouldn't work as intended. Instead of `orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type List<Book>`, it simply gave `orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Book` instead which leads me to believe that there's something fundementally wrong with either how the exception handler is written or with how it's interacting with the method.

I've tried a variety of smaller changes, namely syntax, but but none of them have had any effect whatsoever.

Any help is appreciated as this has been a thorn in my side for some time now. Thanks!

## UPDATE

I'm still unsure what changed but when I altered

```
@Override
    public List<Book> getSpecificBook(int id) {
        return bookRepository.findBybookID(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException(id));
    }
```

to

```
@Override
    public Optional<Book> getSpecificBook(int id) {
        return Optional.of(bookRepository.findBybookID(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException(id)));
    }
```

It started working
I forgot to include the fact that I tried this in the original post but I did attempt this and it did not work the last time. It's possible I had other things wrong as well and one or more of my earlier attempts at fixing this issue now allowed this solution to actually work. I'm honestly unsure.

I'll have to do more experimentation with this since the "Optional wrapper doesn't seem to play well with Lists and several of my mappings return that structure. But the core issue of this question appears to be resolved.

Comment: **what you didn't try** - look at the accepted answer of the link you posted.  
*Apparently you refer to the orElseThrow method of the Optional class. The Optional class is a wrapper around an object reference. An Optional object either contains a payload (a reference to another object) or contains nothing.*  **You are not using `Optional` in your code**

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've updated the post with the results of attempting your solution. I'm not sure how but it worked this time.

Comment: I don't think you really understand what's happening.  `return Optional.of(bookRepository.findBybookID(id)).orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException(id))` is exactly equivalent to `bookRepository.findBybookID(id)`.  `orElseThrow` does nothing for you in that code.